# python append list return none

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following code to generate a list of tuples:

```
list_of_tuples = list()

for name in list_of_names:
    temporary_list = [name]
    date = function_that_return_a_list      #like ['2014', '01', '20']
    temporary_list = temporary_list + date
    print temporary_list    #returns the correct list of [name, '2014', '01', '20']
    list_of_tuples.append(temporary_list)     #crashes with the error message "TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (0 given)"

print flist
```

The problem seem to be related to that the append and insert functions return None when I try and use them on the date list

Comment: What happens when you do:
`list_of_tuples.append(tuple(temporary_list))`

Comment: Could you rather provide a runnable [SSCE](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't produce an error for me (when replacing `function_that_return_a_list` with `['2014', '01', '20']`), nor does the error message make sense. Can you a) provide us with the *full* traceback of the exception and b) a code example that actually produces the exception?

Comment: The code you have provided does not produce any error. Please provide a code example...

Comment: @user2856110: *descriptor*? Then you didn't *call* `list()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to **call** the `list()` type:

```
list_of_tuples = list()
#    ----------------^ You didn't do this.
```

Your exception (as posted in the comments) shows that you tried to call `.append` on the type object instead:

```
>>> list.append(())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor 'append' requires a 'list' object but received a 'tuple'
>>> list().append(())
```

Better use `[]` to produce an empty list in any case:

```
list_of_tuples = []
```