# Python Append to a list returns none

Tags: python, append

I know different versions of this question has been answered for example [here].[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21234442/python-append-list-return-none) But I just couldn't seem to get it working on my example. I am trying to make a copy of ListA called ListB and then add an additional item to ListB i.e. 'New_Field_Name' in which later on I use as column headers for a dataframe.

Here is my code:

```
ListA = ['BUSINESSUNIT_NAME' ,'ISONAME', 'Planning_Channel', 'Planning_Partner', 'Is_Tracked', 'Week', 'Period_Number']
print type(ListA)
```

Output:

```
ListB = list(ListA)
print '######', ListB, '#####'
```

Output:
    ###### ['BUSINESSUNIT_NAME', 'ISONAME', 'Planning_Channel', 'Planning_Partner', 'Is_Tracked', 'Week', 'Period_Number'] #####

```
ListB = ListB.append('New_Field_Name')
print type(ListB)
print ListB
```

Output:
    
    None

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`append` does not return anything, so you cannot say

```
ListB = ListB.append('New_Field_Name')
```

It modifies the list in place, so you just need to say

```
ListB.append('New_Field_Name')
```

Or you could say

```
ListB += ['New_Field_Name']
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that it's a convention in Python that functions that modify a mutable object in-place return `None`.

Comment: Thanks Cyber, it is clear for me now. It has been flagged as a duplicate question although I this example highlights the issue in a more concise manner.